# Finding the class of objects passed to `...` in R?

Tags: r, function, class

I'm trying to find an appropriate R code for the word `does not contain` in my function (`foo`) below?

In other words, how can I make sure that objects that are passed to `...` contain *at least one instance* of class `"POSIXt"` in them?

```
A <- Sys.time()
B <- as.POSIXlt(A)

foo <- function(...){

 if(class(list(...)) does not contain "POSIXt") stop("Error") ## Send a Message
}

foo(A, B)
```

Comment: If you need the custom error message, use `stop`

Comment: So, I assume that you want to have all the arguments to be POSIXt instead of at least one

Comment: In that case, it is `if(!(any(sapply(list(...), inherits, "POSIXt")))) stop("Error")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `POSIXlt` class is `%in%` any of the arguments passed, we loop through the `list` ('l1') get the `class` and check whether `POSIXt` is `%in%` that `class`

```
foo <- function(...){
  l1 <- list(...)
  if("POSIXt" %in% unlist(sapply(l1, class))) "Good Class" else "Bad Class"

}

foo(A, B)
#[1] "Good Class"

foo(LETTERS[1:4], 1:5, letters[1:3])
#[1] "Bad Class"
```

---

Or use the `inherits`

```
foo <- function(...){
 l1 <- list(...)
  if(any(sapply(l1, inherits, "POSIXct"))) "Good Class" else "Bad Class"
 }

foo(LETTERS[1:4], 1:5, letters[1:3])
#[1] "Bad Class"
```

#### Update

If we need to stop if there is not any `POSIXct`

```
foo <- function(...){
   l1 <- list(...)
   stopifnot(any(sapply(l1, inherits, "POSIXct")))
}

foo(LETTERS[1:4], 1:5, letters[1:3])
```

> Error: any(sapply(l1, inherits, "POSIXct")) is not TRUE

```
foo(A, 1:5) #no error
```

---

Or if we need a custom error message, use `stop` as @rnorouzian metnioned in the comments

```
foo <- function(...){
   if(!(any(sapply(list(...), inherits, "POSIXt")))) stop("Error") 


  }
foo(A, B) #no error
foo(LETTERS[1:4], 1:5, letters[1:3])
```

> Error in foo(LETTERS[1:4], 1:5, letters[1:3]) : Error